# Opening/Sharing Exchange Calendars in Outlook for Mac 2011

Tags: windows-7, macos, microsoft-outlook, calendar

**Problem (in short)**: Mac users cannot open/share calendars in Outlook.

**Background:**

I have five users who need to work on one calendar in Outlook. Three users are running Microsoft Outlook 2010 on Windows 7. The other two users are running Microsoft Outlook 2011 for Mac on Mountain Lion.

The person who owns the calendar to be shared with everyone else has a Windows 7 computer. After having shared the calendar with the other four people, we realized that only Windows users could open it, as they received an invitation e-mail with a link in it. Clicking the link would open up the calendar.

**Problem (detailed):**

Mac users received the same e-mail, but no link. So, I went to Open calendar on the mac, looked for the name of the person sharing the calendar, and tried adding it that way. The error I received said that I did not have permission to view the calendar. So, I had the mac users log in to Windows 7 computers, open outlook and click on the link in the e-mail(which now showed up). They were able to add the calendar. I had the mac users log back into the mac, but the calendar was not there.

Next, I had a mac user create a calendar in Outlook and share it with the four other users. That triggered an error saying the permissions could not be saved.

**The server:**

We are running Microsoft Exchange Server 2007.

Any ideas on what to do next? The objective is to share an outlook calendar with both Windows and Mac users.

Comment: Outlook for Mac has all kind of issues, someone said its a punishment from Microsoft for using a Mac. Have you seen these solutions ? https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/3007307 , https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/2743766 , https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/2743752

Answer (score 0):

Are you running an in house Exchange server or are you on a hosted platform? 
Do you have access to OWA?
If your user has access to OWA have the MAC users go to OWA to accept the invite once they do that they would then be able to view the calendar

Comment: There is no link to accept the invite in OWA. As mentioned before, I had users log in on Windows PCs and add the calendar in Outlook, but that does not carry over to other systems.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are an organization and should instead be configuring the permissions on the backend.  The email is irrelevant in an exchange environment.  I realize this is 8 years old.

Look into powershell `get` and `set-mailboxfolderpermissions`.  If a user has permission there, all they need to do is add the calendar as long as they are in the same organization.  If they are external, that's a whole different story.